# On dit "Validateur" ou "Valideur" ?

Tags: usage, orthographe

Comment on nomme une personne qui valide une opération, **validateur** ou **valideur**

Comment: Mon père utilisait le terme *inspecteur des travaux finis*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ça dépend du sens et du contexte. « Valider » a quatre sens : l'acte de déclarer que quelque chose est valide, l'acte de confirmer que quelque chose est valide, l'investigation cherchant à déterminer si quelque chose est valide, et le travail cherchant à rendre quelque chose valide. Les noms associés ne sont pas forcément les mêmes.

La personne qui est responsable de la décision de déclarer quelque chose valide est le ou la ***[décisionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9cisionnaire)***. Ce mot peut être adjectif (« qui a le pouvoir de décision ») ou un nom (« personne qui a le pouvoir de décision »). Quelqu'un qui fait des recherches pour déterminer si quelque chose est valide est souvent un ***[enquêteur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/enqu%C3%AAteur)***, mais cela dépend du contexte, et le rôle d'un enquêteur est avant tout de réunir des données et moins de les analyser. Un ***[analyste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/analyste)*** est quelqu'un qui analyse des données, mais ce nom est peu utilisé : en général on utilise un nom qui dépend du type de données et d'analyse.

Les mots *[valideur/valideuse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/valideur)* et *[validateur/validatrice](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/validateur)* sont tous les deux employés comme adjectifs et comme noms dans les sens de « déclarer que quelque chose est valide » ou de « déterminer si quelque chose est valide », dans des contextes différents. Mais aucun n'est habituellement utilisé pour une personne, au moins en France. Pour une personne, on utilise plutôt une expression telle que ***[chargé(e) de validation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22charg%C3%A9+de+validation%22)*** ou ***[responsable de validation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22responsable+de+validation%22)***.

Dans le vocabulaire administratif, on parle d'***[organisme valideur](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22organisme+valideur%22)*** pour un organisme qui est à la fois chargé de déterminer si quelque chose est valide et de déclarer officiellement la validité. (Le terme ***organisme [homologateur](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22organisme+homologateur)*** existe aussi lorsque la validation est une [homologation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/homologation).) On parle de ***valideur*** pour un appareil qui détermine si un titre de transport est valide (si l'appareil modifie le billet pour marquer qu'il a été utilisé, on parle de ***composteur***). On parle de ***valideuse*** pour un appareil qui détermine si un billet de loterie est valide.

L'adjectif *validateur* a surtout le sens de « confirmant la validité ». Le nom *validateur* est surtout utilisé pour un outil logiciel qui détermine si quelque chose est valide ; c'est un import de l'anglais [plus récent que *valideur*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=valideur%2Cvalidateur%2Cvalideuse%2Cvalidatrice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3). L'OQLF (organisme officiel Québecois) mentionne le nom *[validateur](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17558707)* comme terme déconseillé pour « personne chargée de vérifier l'exactitude scientifique d'une publication » et recommande « expert(e) consulté(e) » ; en France je n'ai jamais vu *validateur* utilisé dans ce sens (on parle traditionnellement de *relecteur* là où l'anglais utilise *reviewer*, mais ce terme a tendance à disparaître parce qu'il donne l'impression qu'un relecteur ne fait que vérifier les détails de la présentation et pas la véracité du propos).

Comment: J'aime bien le terme *décisionnaire*, je trouve que c'est celui qui se rapproche le plus du sens recherché si on est dans le cadre d'une activité professionnelle.

Comment: Bien sûr: chargé(e) de validation ou responsable de validation. approbateur et validateur seraient des adjectifs en français.

Answer (score 2):

J'aurais tendance à ne choisir aucun des deux pour désigner une personne qui valide une opération. À la place, j'utiliserais le terme [**approbateur**](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/approbateur/4761).

Par exemple :

> Nous ne pouvons pas considérer ce projet comme terminé tant que le client, qui est le seul approbateur, n'est pas satisfait du résultat.

Pour répondre à la question sur le terme "valideur/validateur", voici un petit rappel des définitions :

- [Valideur](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/valideur/10910808) :

> Appareil permettant aux voyageurs de valider un titre de transport [...].

- [Validateur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/validateur) :

> (Adj.) Qui valide.

ou

> (Informatique) Outil informatique qui valide, qui fait une validation.

Donc par rapport au sens recherché dans la question, le terme le plus proche est *validateur*, **mais il n'est pas très approprié dans le contexte d'une personne** car il s'agit avant tout d'un terme informatique.

Comment: Je valide ! :-)

Comment: Non, *approbateur* est un contresens. Quelqu'un d'approbateur est quelqu'un qui est d'accord (*approving*), pas quelqu'un dont l'accord compte (*approver*). Il est possible que le sens soit en train d'évoluer par analogie avec l'anglais *approver*, mais en 2022, si on me dit « Jean est approbateur », je comprends que Jean est d'accord, pas que c'est lui qui décide. En lisant la phrase que tu donnes en exemple, ma première réaction est qu'il y a une contradiction (parce que *approbateur* et *satisfait* sont synonymes), et ensuite seulement je pense à un éventuel jargon franglais.

Comment: @Gilles Un approbateur (nom commun) peut être désapprobateur (adjectif). C'est peut-être du jargon mais on peut aussi dire qu'on remet au gout du jour un sens existant  (*Censeur qui donnait. l'approbation officielle à un ouvrage avant son impression*). Un approbateur est pour moi une personne qui dispose des privilèges qui permettent d'approuver (donc valider) une demande ou un projet ou de les rejeter/refuser.

Comment: C'est vrai que la question ne donne pas de détails sur ce qu'est l'opération à valider.

Comment: J'aurais utilisé **contrôleur** plutôt qu'**approbateur**.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' C'est possible que j'aie été influencé par mon environnement professionnel (je travaille en startup, où il y a beaucoup d'anglicismes). Clairement, dans ma tête le mot *approbateur* s'emploie comme l'anglais *approver*. Merci pour ton commentaire et ta réponse qui remettent les choses en perspective. :)

Comment: @jlliagre À ma connaissance le nom « approbateur » dans ce sens n'était utilisé que dans un contexte de censure où l'on n'utiliserait pas le verbe « valider ». Quant à l'histoire de la langue, les exemples que je trouve sur Internet d'« approbateur » comme nom désignant quelqu'un qui prend une décision d'approuver ou nom sont tous des traductions plus ou moins directes de l'anglais (souvent l'approbateur d'un « workflow ») à part sur des sites Suisses. Peut-être que le nom serait compris dans ce sens en Suisse.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' traduction directe de quoi? Le substantif approval comme adjective? L'anglais n'a pas "approver". Un ton approbateur. Par exemple. En français. An approving tone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134794/discussion-on-answer-by-reyedy-on-dit-validateur-ou-valideur).